# Achieving an elastic effect in a jquery based slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I've seen a couple of examples of this, don't know exactly what it is called or how it is implemented.  As of this post, if you go to http://www.ibm.com/us/en/ you will see the slider effect I'm talking about.

It pulls part of the content off to the left a little bit ahead of the content on the right, as if there are two divs connected by a piece of elastic.

Looks like a div containing an image, on top of another div with the second image.  Are they doing this by stacking two sliders on top of each other, and firing the second one after the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an tutorial that will help you:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/

The demo:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/

Comment: ok thanks, I will see if I can get that technique to work the way I described...thank you for the reference.